# Javascript create next() function OOP way

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

i have a problem for creating next() function with OOP way.

this is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/s5e1530c/

```
"use strict";

var i, j, arr, loop, $;

(function() {

    $ = function(el, context) {
        context = context || document;
        return new obj$(el, context);
    };

    var obj$ = function(el, context) {

        if (context == null) {
            var cl   = context.getElementsByClassName(el),
                loop = cl.length;

            this.length = loop;

            for (i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
                this[i] = cl[i];
            }

        }
        else {
            var cl   = context,
                loop = cl.length;

            this.length = loop;

            for (i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
                this[i] = cl[i];
            }

        }   


       return this;

    };

    obj$.prototype = {

       next : function() {

        if (this.length == 1) {

          return $(this[0], this[0].nextElementSibling);

        }

        return $();

       },
       css : function(obj, data) {

           if (this.length == 1) {
               this[0].style[obj] = data;

           }

           return this;

        }
    };

})();

<div class="child">child</div>
<div class="next">Next</div>

var child     = $("child"),
    nextchild = child.next();

nextchild.css("color", "red");
```

why this code not working? there are no error on console.

what's wrong with my code?

thanks in advance......

Comment: a lot of issues, im not doing all the work for you, so go a head and look what i left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function() {
"use strict";

    var i, j, arr, loop, $, Obj$;

$ = function(el, context) {
    context = context || document;
    return new Obj$(el, context);
};

Obj$ = function(el, context) {

  if(typeof el == "object") {

   //take care of objects here


  }
   /*
   why would context be null? It's either context or document
   if (context == null) {
        var cl   = context.getElementsByClassName(el),
            loop = cl.length;

        this.length = loop;

        for (i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
            this[i] = cl[i];
        }

    }
    else {
    */
        var cl   = context.getElementsByClassName(el),
            loop = cl.length;

        this.length = loop;

        for (i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
            this[i] = cl[i];
        }

    //}   


   return this;

};

Obj$.prototype = {

   next : function() {
    //why do equals 1? Do greater than or equal to 1
    if (this.length >= 1) {
      return $(this[0].nextElementSibling);

    }
     //return undefiend not an empty object
    return undefined;

   },
   css : function(obj, data) {

       if (this.length >= 1) {
           this[0].style[obj] = data;
       }

       return this;

    }
};

window.$ = $;
})();

var child  = $("child"),
nextchild = child.next();

nextchild.css("color", "red");
```

You have a lot of work to do to get yours to work the way you want. For one your selector process is very weak, two your understanding of lengths and objects is very weak as well.